# Self referential type - is it possible?

Tags: typescript

I have a function that accepts a configuration object with some color definitions.

Example:

```
useColors({
  colors: {
    RED: { hex: 0xff0000 },
    GREEN: { hex: 0x00ff00 },
    BLUE: { hex: 0x0000ff }
  },
  doSomethingWithColor(getColor) {
    getColor('RED') // should accept "RED" | "GREEN" | "BLUE"
  }
})
```

It also accepts a function `doSomethingWithColor`, and I want its callback parameter type to be a union of the colors inferred from the configuration object itself.

Is this possible with TypeScript?

Comment: This is not good design. You are passing in a function `getColor` into an object's member function `doSomethingWithColor`, and the only purpose of `getColor` is to accept one of the colors defined inside this config object's `colors` property and return its value. You should consider making `getColor` a member function or remove the use of `getColor` and have `doSomethingWithColor` accept an actual color name (`RED`, `GREEN`, `BLUE`, etc)

Comment: Consider something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WzyVem)

Comment: This is just a simplified example of a real codebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using generics:

```js
function useColors<ColorMap>(config: {
  colors: ColorMap,
  doSomethingWithColor: (getColor: <K extends keyof ColorMap>(color: K) => ColorMap[K]) => void;
}) {
  const getColor = <K extends keyof ColorMap>(c: K) => config.colors[c];
  config.doSomethingWithColor(getColor);
}
```

If you use the above snippet, the objects in `ColorMap` can differ from each other:

```
useColors({
  colors: {
    RED: { hexR: 0xff0000 },
    GREEN: { hexG: 0x00ff00 },
    BLUE: { hexB: 0x0000ff }
  },
  doSomethingWithColor(getColor) {
    const val = getColor("GREEN") // val's type is { hexG: number }
  }
})
```

But you can also restrict the values of the ColorMap to the shape you desire using something like:

```js
function useColors<ColorMap extends Record<string, { hex: number }>>(config: {
  colors: ColorMap,
  doSomethingWithColor: (getColor: <K extends keyof ColorMap>(color: K) => ColorMap[K]) => void;
}) {
  const getColor = <K extends keyof ColorMap>(c: K) => config.colors[c];
  config.doSomethingWithColor(getColor);
}
```